# need to implement exchnage server

Tags: exchange, email-server

actually i need to implement the Microsoft exchange server 2010 in my office for 20 email accounts.

which version i should prefer

Exchange Server 2010 Standard Edition
Exchange Server 2010 Enterprise Edition

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise Edition is not needed - [see here for details](http://www.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/en/us/licensing.aspx).